# How to pass DOM element and JSON object to JavaScript function if the code is generated?

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have the following jQuery/Javascript code snippet. This snippet is intended to insert a new `div` element as a child of a DOM Element that  already exists on the page. The `div` element contains a text label "myLabel". When someone clicks on "myLabel", I would like it to call `myFunction` with two parameters: one JSON object and one DOMElement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // myDOMElement is a DOM object acquired by doing document.getElementById()
    // myFunction is a Javascript function defined elsewhere
    myJSONObject = {"Hello": "World"};
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "myNewDivID");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<span id=\"mySpanID\" onclick=\"myFunction('" + myJSONObject +"', '" + myDOMElement + "');\">myLabel</span>";
});
```

This code doesn't work when I click on "myLabel".

The problem lies in the way I am passing in `myJSONObject` and `myDOMElement` to `myFunction`.

In `myFunction` they get printed out as the strings "`[object Object]`" and "`[object HTMLDivElement]`" respectively. Obviously this is because of the single-quote I have inserted just inside the parenthesis in the call to the function. But if I remove those single quotes, then it doesn't work because the definition of `onclick` now contains syntax errors.

How can I escape strings or parse/de-parse around this issue so that I can manipulate `myDOMElement` and `myJSONObject` in `myFunction`?

Comment: You can try attaching the click handler dynamically, and using a regular JS function?

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously using jQuery, so use it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myJSONObject = {"Hello": "World"};
    var newDiv = $('<div />',  {id : 'myNewDivID'}),
    var span   = $('<span />', {id : 'mySpanID', text : 'myLabel'});

    span.on('click', function() {
        // use myJSONObject and "this" here
    });

    $('#target_element').append( newDiv.append(span) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the click handler dynamically, that is:

```
function myFunction(jsonObject, element) {
    console.log(jsonObject);
    console.log(element);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    myJSONObject = {"Hello": "World"};
    var newDiv = $('<div id="myNewDivID"/>');
    var span = $('<span id="mySpanID">');
    span.text('myLabel');
    span.on('click', myFunction.bind(undefined, myJSONObject, 'this would be the element'));
    newDiv.append(span);
});
```

Calling `myFunction.bind()` returns a new function with the arguments to `myFunction` preset. The first argument to `bind` is what `this` will be set to, but because jQuery will (I think) use `call` to call the event handler, it doesn't really matter.

If you want access to the event as well, you can add a accept another argument to `myFunction`, i.e.:

```
function myFunction(jsonObject, element, event) {
    // Do things.
}
```

Without jQuery:

```
function myFunction(jsonObject, element) {
    console.log(jsonObject);
    console.log(element);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    myJSONObject = {"Hello": "World"};
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'myNewDivId');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('id', 'mySpanId');
    span.innerText = 'words'; // or textContent?
    span.addEventListener('click', myFunction.bind(window, myJSONObject, 'this would be the element'));
    div.appendChild(span);
});
```